# pnp4nagios rrd multivalue breakout

Tags: nagios

I set up a nagios check script to track user quota usage on our Netapps, produces perfdata just fine. I set the perfdata as multiple value so I get a single *Hostname*.xml and a rrd per user. Graphs gen just fine, just takes page awhile to display, understandably for 140+ users. Ideally I want to view graph page (daily,weekly,monthly, etc) per user. Unsure how to proceed. Custom template? Custom page? Any pointers?

Comment: Can you clarify what you have now and are asking for? If the graphs gen fine with an RRD per user why do you say you want to generate a graph page per user? Is that not the same thing?

Comment: What is generated, by default is a single page with daily/weekly/monthly graphs for 140+ users. I want a single page per user. Something I plan on linking to via a html report.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're currently doing it sounds fine, but you should throw [rrdcached](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcached.en.html) in the mix to fix the performance problems.

The [pnp4nagios docs](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/rrdcached) (assuming 0.6) show how to integrate with rrdcached. (Or, if using [pnp4nagios 0.4](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.4/rrdcached).)

Comment: Not too worried about the performance since the current default single page with daily/weekly/monthly graphs for 140+ users is not the desired end result. I want a single page per user. Something I plan on linking to via a html report.